# Связаные таблицы в БД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Попал мне дамп БД увидел в нем связанные таблицы, вот скрин из phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Вопрос: как можно самому связывать таблицы, и как это можно использовать в PHP, ведь связи делаются не только для просмотра в phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Освежите в памяти информацию о [внешних ключах](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp). Делается всё это для [нормализации БД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно написать SQL-запрос таким образом, чтобы ваш FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) в одной таблице соответствовал PRIMARY KEY (видимо, `id`) в другой. Т.е.

```
select *
from table_1 t1, table_2 t2
where t1.id = t2.category_id
...
;
```